# I need help with the color to alpha tool on gimp

Tags: gimp

So I used the color to alpha tool in gimp and it did what I wanted it to but when I saved and exported the picture it didn't apply. what I wanted is to take all the white values and make them transparent which is what it appeared to do. but when I opened it in another software I have it didn't register as transparent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you save in a file format that supports transparency, such as PNG or gif?

Comment: From your screenshot it appears you had exported the image to JPG which does not support transparency.

Comment: As Takkat's comments. Export to a format that support transparency such as PNG.